# c#: Search the DataGridView columns text both in Upper and Lower cases

Tags: c#

I want to search the `DataGridView` columns text both in `Upper` and `Lower` cases, which is being input through `text box`. I used the following code which search the string but only if matching the exact case. I need that text string  case should be either upper or lower

```
        string searchstring = textBox1.Text;
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (searchstring == "")
                    row.Selected = false;
                else
                {
                   if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(searchstring))
                   {
                        this.dataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;
                        row.Selected = true;
                        int indx = row.Index;
                    }
                    else
                        row.Selected = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: You could use the `ToLowerInvariant()` at both sides...

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are trying to match strings without worrying about case. Instead of using `Contains()`, try using `String.Equals()` and pass in the [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_StringComparison_OrdinalIgnoreCase) parameter. That is what ignores case.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings) is a good link on string comparison.

```
string val = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
if (String.Equals(val, searchstring, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // do work
}
```